# Ayuda!! conexion y visualizacion de datos PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola a todos espero esten bien :), tengo el siguiente problema.

Quiero mostrar datos en una tabla desde mysql usando php pero me aparece lo siguiente.

[image: El Error que me tira :(]

este es mi codigo no se que estoy haciendo mal

```js
//codigo PHP de la conexion a la base
<?php

$usuario = "root";
$contraseña= "";
$servidor="localhost";
$basedatos="base_ihadfa";

//conexion a la base de datos
  $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$contraseña);
  mysqli_select_db($conexion, $basedatos);
  
?>
**-------------Codigo de la tabla--------------**
```

```html
//codigo de la tabla
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Ejemplo de interaccion con DB</title>
<style type="text/css">
@import url("css/mycss.css");
</style>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="todo">
  
  <div id="cabecera">
   <img src="images/swirl.png" width="1188" id="img1">
  </div>
  
   <!--Tabla de contenido-->
  <div id="contenido">
   <table style="margin: auto; width: 800px; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px 5px;">
    <thead>
     <th>Nombres</th>
     <th>Apellidos</th>
     <th>Identidad</th>
     <th>Correo</th>
        <th>Usuario</th>
        <th>Nivel de Permiso</th>
     <th> <a href="nuevo_prod1.php"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Registrar Nuevo Usuario</button> </a> </th>
    </thead>
**------------------codigo php para mostrar los datos en la tabla------------**
 <!--Mostrar los datos en la tabla// codigo php-->
    <?php
       //llamar archivo de la conexion BD
      include "conexion.php";
      
      //sentencia de la BD, se almacena dentro de una variable para tener mas eficiencia
      $sentencia="SELECT * FROM usuario";
      
      //acontinuacion se le dice que muestre todo lo de la tabla usuarios y lo almacene en la variable resultado
      $resultado=mysqli_query($sentencia);
      
      //se usa while para imprimir en la tabla los datos que estan en la base de datos
      while($filas=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
      {
        echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Nombres']; echo "</td>";
          echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Apellidos']; echo "</td>";
          echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Identidad']; echo "</td>";
          echo "<td>"; echo $filas['correo']; echo "</td>";
          echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Usuario']; echo "</td>";
          echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Password']; echo "</td>";
          echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Nivel_Permiso']; echo "</td>";
          echo "<td>  <a href='modif_prod1.php?no=".$filas['no']."'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>Modificar</button> </a> </td>";
          
          echo "<td> <a href='eliminar_prod.php?no=".$filas['no']."''><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Eliminar</button></a> </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
      }

      ?>
   </table>
  </div>
  
 <div id="footer">
    <img src="images/swirl2.png" id="img2">
   </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

-----------gracias por sus respuesta-------

Comment: mysqli_query() necesita dos parámetros para que se ejecute, la conexión y la sentencia: $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $sentencia);

Comment: Compartenos tu código de `conexion.php`.`mysqli_query();` necesita dos parámetros, uno es la conexión contra la bd y el otro es la sentencia sql, en tu caso `$sentencia`.